Change material through editor script shows result only cursor hovers into scene view or game view
I made a script to adjust color and values of a material in editor mode. Its sturcture looks like this.
  private void OnGUI()
    {
        if (basicTextilePreset.Count != 5)
        {
            LoadBasic();
        }

        if (material != null)
        {
            if (material != _nowMaterial)
            {

                SaveOriginalValues();
                _nowMaterial = material;
                _nowTextileType = TextileType;

                Select();
            }
            if (material == _nowMaterial)
            {
                if (TextileType != _nowTextileType)
                {
                    _nowTextileType = TextileType;

                    Select();
                }
                else
                {
                    ChangeMaterialDynamically();
                }

            }
        }
        if (material == null && _nowMaterial != null)
        {
            _nowMaterial = null;
            originalTextilePreset = null;
        }

    }

and this is the inspector screenshot of the component
(https://i.sstatic.net/9QDm9OOK.png)
As you can see, this script adjust values and color(ChangeMaterialDynamically method) when OnGUI is called. And as far as I know, OnGUI is called for endering and handling GUI events. So I thought adjusting material value through this script inspector would show result right away as soon as I adjust something.
But its result isnt shown right away. It is shown only after cursor hovers into scene view or game view if I display game view and scene view at the same time in editor.
I display game view and scene view at the same time in editor](https://i.sstatic.net/65TTp97B.png)
or if I see one between game view and scene view, the result sometimes isnt applied or applied after few seconds.
This script runs in edit mode(execute in edit mode), so I tried to force update using method below
   public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        base.OnInspectorGUI();

        if (GUI.changed)
        {

            UnityEditorInternal.InternalEditorUtility.RepaintAllViews();
            EditorApplication.QueuePlayerLoopUpdate();
            EditorApplication.update();
            EditorApplication.RepaintProjectWindow();
            EditorApplication.RepaintHierarchyWindow();
            EditorApplication.RepaintAnimationWindow();
            SceneView.RepaintAll();

        }


    }

I wrote them in OnGUI in my script. But nothing changed( I guess). Still update is applied after few seconds or not applied unless I see game view and scene view at the same time in editor.

OnGUI and OnInspectorGUI are not called continuously but only when redrawing is actually required - for instance when the mouse moves within them or user interacts with the UI.
if you need direct updates rather use a callback to EditorApplication.update

I wrote that in  ChangeMaterialDynamically(), but still material change still shows after I hover mouse cursor on game view.
